# How make to JS Multi Buttons?

Tags: javascript

I have buttons named 1,2 and 3. Below it are a, b, c, d buttons. When I click the 1st button and click the "A" button, I get the (Test Test2) warning. But I cannot click the 2nd button and click the "A" button. I want to give another warning. For example: I clicked the 1st button and then I clicked the A button, as it says (Test Test6) on the screen, but I couldn't. Thanks.

```js
var firstButtonPressed = false;
function onFirstButtonClick() {
  firstButtonPressed = true;
}

function onfourButtonClick() {
  if(firstButtonPressed) {
    alert('Test Test2');
    firstButtonPressed = false;
  } else {
    alert('Test2');
  }
  return;
}


var secondButtonPressed = false;
function onSecondButtonClick(){
  secondButtonPressed = true;
}

function onFourButtonClick(){
  if(secondButtonPressed){
    alert('Button2 Test');
    secondButtonPressed = false;
  }else {
    alert ('61 Tes-t')
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="onFirstButtonClick()">1<br><br>Button</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="onSecondButtonClick()">2<br><br>Button</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="onThirdButtonClick()">3<br><br>Button</button>
  <br /><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="onfourButtonClick()">A</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="onfiveButtonClick()">B</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="onsixButtonClick()">C</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="onsevenButtonClick()">D</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, clarify your question. It very hard to understand.

Comment: Example: I clicked button 1, then when I clicked button A (Test Test) message is written.
Briefly, I click on the 2nd button and then I click on the A button (Test Test2) and it is written as a message.

Comment: The code you wrote here, i can't find any "test test3" or "test test4" msgs.
Also, `onfiveButtonClick` and other functions not exists. I've confused too what you're willing.

Comment: It should give a warning ('Button2 Test') when pressing the A button with the 2nd button. Only onfourButtonClick is full others are not defined.

Comment: When is `onFourButtonClick()` called? I think you've confused with `onfourButtonClick()`

Comment: Solved my problem thanks. My problem right now is: When I click the 1st button and click the A button, I have to click the 1st button again to click the B button. What I want to do is is it possible to click the 1st button and click the a, b, c buttons?

Comment: just use same code - that is, checking `if (firstButtonPressed)` is common for all other buttons. The difference maybe a alert msg.

Comment: Can you describe what the purpose of this is? I don't understand why you want to click a button in order to click another button. Is this some form of confirmation of user intent?

Comment: No, this is not an endorsement. You can think of the first clicked buttons as a car model. We clicked on the model, the purpose of clicking the other button is to choose a color. I made the color selection, but I cannot change the colors on top of each other, in short, I have to click the model button again to choose a color.